# Waving hands classically

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

Waving one's hands can mean avoiding details or drawing attention away from a lie of an unsupported part of an argument or story.
There is an entire [Wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-waving) if you want more detail.

I would like to know how to wave hands in classical Latin.
More precisely:

- Does any direct translation of waving hands (like *manus iactare*) have an idiomatic non-literal meaning?
- What would be a good way to express hand-waving in classical Latin? Is there a verb, noun, or other phrase that captures the idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quintilian, whose students were hoping to make it in the professional world, is very conventional. He tells them to avoid too many jokes, cut down on the metaphors, and certainly none of that tricksy Greek word play with clever-clever hidden meaning.  So he tells his students to avoid any sort of arm-waving.

> ***Gestio, gestire, gestivi*** or ***gestii,*** old imperfect ***gestibant.***
>   **2.** Figurative, rambling, and digression.  Quintilian 10, 5,15.

But for Ovid, Livy, Cicero **gestio** is just enthusiastic  body language. If you want to talk about silly arm-waving, that would be...

> ***Gesticulor, -atus*** to gesticulate, to mime, to make pantomime gestures.

Notice the derisory diminutive **-cul-** (cf. cacula, -ae *m.* rare, a military page')

Apologies for an over personal, opinionated view. Fritz Graf offers a fuller, more balanced view in a pdf which has a section on Quintilian.

Comment: What is *scacula*? I can't find it in L&S.

Comment: @TKR appears to be a misprint for *cacula* !st m. a military page; a soldier’s servant or slave. (Plautus)